# Alignment of buttons in view

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have 4 buttons in an row, how can i align this in the middle on each device? iphone 4s, iphone 5s, iphone 6, iphone 6 plus.

Only on the iphone 6 it looks good. On the iphone 4s the buttons going outside the view and  on the 5s and 6 plus is it not centered.

On the left view you see the layout, and the right view you see an preview.
[image]
How can i fix this issue? I have tried auto layout but this doesn't work..

Here with the constraint alignment (horizontal) on each button. But they are not in the middle..

[image]

thank you.

Comment: Have you set constraints in interface builder? This is quite simple to do.

Comment: I have tried that, but this doesn't work for me. Or i am doing it wrong.

Comment: What constraints did you add?

Comment: The alignment (horizontal) on each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something here. But is it all that you need, to have multiple buttons centered vertically in the container and also horizontally (with no overlap and good symmetry). If so, you can do the below.

The constraints are -

1. Button A - Center vertically in container
2. Button B:Center Y = Button A:Center Y;  Button C:Center Y = Button B:Center Y
3. Button A: Leading space to superview = some constant (say 30)
4. Button C: Trailing space to superview = same constant as above
5. Horizontal spacing (Button A - Button B) = Horizontal spacing (Button B - Button C) = some constant (say 10)
6. Width (Button A) = Width (Button B) = Width (Button C)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To align multiple buttons in the center of the canvas, you can place two "dummy" or "helper" views on each side. Then apply the following constraints:

- `equal width` for the two dummy views.
- `leading space to superview = 0` for the left dummy view.
- `trailing space to superview = 0` for the right dummy view.
- `horizontal spacing = 0` for the dummy view and the button.
- `horizontal spacing = some fixed value` for the buttons.

You can set the dummy view's height to `0`.

Below is an example in the storyboard. For the sake of simplicity, I only included two buttons. You can have as many buttons as you like using this method.

[image]